# Windows 10 disable automatic defragmentation

Tags: windows-10

How to disable automatic defragmentation in Windows 10? It is scanning my 2 TB HDD for 2 hours already and lags too much.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/f98c9z :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In addition to the method geotavros described, another method for turning off automatic defrag/optimization can be accomplished by doing the following....

1. Click on the `Start Menu`
2. Start typing `Defrag` and you'll see an option come up called `Defragment and Optimize Drives`. Select that.
3. Make sure the drive you want to turn off defrag/optimize is highlighted and then click on `Change Settings`.
4. Uncheck the box that says `Run on a schedule`
5. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> and you're done.

[image]

Comment: Seems like defrag will be turned off for all drives instead of just the selected drive, same for turning it on. Have W10 Home V1709

Comment: How did you create this gif ? @n8te

Comment: @ChamindaBandara - I used a program called [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek). It's only available for Linux. I made a remote desktop connection from my Linux PC to a Windows laptop and recorded the Windows desktop from my Linux PC using Peek.

Comment: @ChamindaBandara Use [ScreenToGif](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif/).

Answer (score 4):

Open an administrative cmd prompt (or Powershell, up to you) and execute:

```
schtasks /Change /DISABLE /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Defrag\ScheduledDefrag"
```

This command disables the task, just as the original question asks and is a faster, cmd line-based solution that functions identically to [the top GUI answer from n8te](https://superuser.com/a/1210465/41374).

This doesn't delete the task, which means that if you decide you need it enabled again at a later date, simply change `DISABLE` to `ENABLE` and run again in an elevated admin prompt:

```
schtasks /Change /ENABLE /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Defrag\ScheduledDefrag"
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative process with Command Prompt::

- Run Command Prompt as administrator and run the command `schtasks /Delete /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Defrag\ScheduledDefrag" /F`

[image: delete scheduled defragmentation with cmd]

- /TN option specifies the path\name of the task to delete.
- /F option forcefully deletes the task and suppresses warnings if the specified task is currently running.

Comment: How can I defrag specific drive like C, D ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara Command as admin: `defrag C: /U /V`.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it via the Task Scheduler > Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > Defrag > then disable the "ScheduledDefrag".